# JS - fetch API, GET method return "ƒ json() { [native code] }"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I woud like to understand the difference between the two get methods, one work, the other not really but i don t understand why.

**This doesn't work:**

```
fetch('https://glo3102lab4.herokuapp.com/fee958c0-c320-40d0-a750-218f2d7c1303/tasks', {
    method: 'GET',
}).then(res => res.json)
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

and return :

> ƒ json() { [native code] }

**This works well:**

```
fetch('https://glo3102lab4.herokuapp.com/fee958c0-c320-40d0-a750-218f2d7c1303/tasks').then(function(response){
    response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Fetch Error:', error);
});
```

and return:

> {tasks: Array(4)} tasks : (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>   **proto** : Object

**If you want to try it:**

```js
fetch('https://glo3102lab4.herokuapp.com/fee958c0-c320-40d0-a750-218f2d7c1303/tasks', {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(res => res.json)
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("first way");
            console.log(response);
        });
        
fetch('https://glo3102lab4.herokuapp.com/fee958c0-c320-40d0-a750-218f2d7c1303/tasks').then(function(response){
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log("second way");
            console.log(data);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Fetch Error:', error);
    });
```

Comment: It's just a typo. In the first case you're returning the actual `json` function (`res => res.json`). In the other case, you're calling the `json` function (`response.json()`) and using the result of it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are returning the `res.json` function. You have to call it and return a Promise:

```
.then(res => res.json())
```

Answer (score 8):

`.json` is a function. you will have to call it. `.then(res => res.json())`

Answer (score 0):

`res.json` is trying to call a function, so change to your code to `res.json()` (add brackets)

Comment: Other answer already explained that. Can you add more details to make your answer unique?